# NET.Core 2.0 IOC issue for unknown constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm getting a bit stuck with NET.Core 2.0 and IOC.

I have different classes that implements IAction Interface, those classes
can have different constructors which I don't know in the scope of the initialization. Here an example :

```
public class UpgradeAction : IAction
{
    protected readonly IUpgradeManager upgradeManager;
    public UpgradeAction(IUpgradeManager upgradeManager)
    {
        this.upgradeManager = upgradeManager;
    }

    public void Process(BaseRequest request)
    {
        upgradeManager.DoUpgrade(request);
    }
}
```

For now I get an error of ParameterLess Constructor if I use this function

```
var t =  (IAction)Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfAction);
```

This one returns a null object.

```
var t = (IAction)serviceProvider.GetService(typeOfAction);
```

Is there any way to initialize IOC configuration to enable that kind of implementation ? So that the specific constructor of the desired class is used to perform the injection.

Actually I added into my startup this, and more. All my IOC is working if I do not pass by that ActionManager (SO the IUpgradeManager is injected directly into my API controller). So I could do this and that's it, but I want to use that ActionManager to enable a pipeline of one command into different processes to make some plugabble architecture.

```
     public void Startup(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IUpgradeManager, UpgradeManager>();
        services.AddTransient<IAction, UpgradeAction>();

        AutoMapper.DefaultMappers(typeof(DataLink).Assembly);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share how you are using the `ActionManager` class?

Comment: You have to register all dependencies for it to work.  What dependencies does `UpgradeManager` have?

Comment: The parameters of the IActions constructor are all registered, and those objects are created correctly, if I remove this in between layer...
But I really would like the actions to be pluginable by extension... internal or by other party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick.

- We get the constructor parameters
- We call the service provider to retrieve the objects of the parameters
- We call the CreateInstance with additional parameters the objects to be used in the constructor.

---

```
var ci = action.GetConstructors().First();
var ciParameters = new List<Object>();
foreach(var parameter in ci.GetParameters())
{                  
    ciParameters.Add(serviceProvider.GetService(parameter.ParameterType));
}
var t = (IAction)Activator.CreateInstance(action, ciParameters.ToArray());
```

---

The other option to use

```
serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(UpgradeAction))
```

is to register the class only :

```
services.AddTransient<UpgradeAction>();
```

Registering the interface is not working. Maybe we need some overloaded method of the GetService to make it work => GetService(type) ?

```
services.AddTransient<IAction, UpgradeAction>();
```

Comment: You are circumventing the whole idea of the DI Container. When configured correctly, it allows you to build deep object graphs for you. So you should request `IAction` from the service provider and it will create an `UpgradeAction` for you with its dependencies.

Comment: The issue is that my IAction can be anything... and that anything can have different constructor parameters, which are registered in the serviceprovider, as you can see I call the service provider to retrieve the correct parameters.

Comment: I could create an empty interface for each of my action, and register them.. but that's a bit overkill... I didn't found any soluyion (yet) in the unity to handle this.

Comment: Just do: `services.AddTransient<UpgradeAction>();` and than resolve `UpgradeAction`.